# Quebra de linha dentro de um input type "search"

Tags: html, input

Como habilitar uma quebra de linha, em um input type="search"? definindo a quantidade de caracteres digitados e a altura da barra search ao identificar uma quantidade especifica de palavras para acontecer uma quebra de linha, ??

```html
<form method="get" action="#endereço.php">
  <input type="search" name="sc"/>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Putzzz, eita, nem a gambiarra? kkk

Comment: Acho que seria um pouco difícil alterar as propriedades do 'search'

Comment: Jessuuzzzz.....

Comment: eu já fiz com textarea, wrap="hard"

Comment: De acordo com essa página: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text (em inglês), não é possível usar um "input" para obter múltiplas linhas. Caso queira, teria que usar <textarea>. Espero ter ajudado.